# Array to string, I get [object HTMLParagraphElement][object HTMLUListElement] instead of value / content

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string

I have an array from a parse

```
odg = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent({ format: "HTML" });

    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const parsedDocument = parser.parseFromString(odg, "text/html");
    const parsedContent = parsedDocument.querySelectorAll(
        "body:not(first-child) > *"
    );


 let array2 = Array.from(parsedContent);
```

I get:

```
Array [ p, ul]
0: <p>​
1: <ul>
length: 2
<prototype>: Array []
```

When I change into string

```
let contentString = array2.join("");
```

I get:

```
[object HTMLParagraphElement][object HTMLUListElement]
```

Instead of: `<p>something</p><ul><li>something else</li></ul>`

What am I missing?

Comment: That is the default `.toString` return value in JS. For instance `({}).toString()` gives `[object Object]`, `[].toString();` gives `[object Array]`, etc.

Comment: what gives me the actual value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

```js
let odg = document.querySelector('container').innerHTML
const parser = new DOMParser();
const parsedDocument = parser.parseFromString(odg, "text/html");
const parsedContent = parsedDocument.querySelectorAll(
  ".findme > *"
);


let array2 = Array.from(parsedContent);
console.log(array2.map(m => m.outerHTML).join(''));
```

```html
<container>
  Ignore me
  <div class='findme'>
    <div>This </div>
    <p>That</p>
  </div>
</container>
```